# Angular Material programmatically add Tabs

Tags: angular, material-design

I want to add and remove tabs from a `mat-tab-group` based on a selection event. The tabs itself hold dynamic tables.

```
<mat-tab-group #tabs>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Its empty at start.

```
<mat-tab [label]="name">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of tableConf.cols" [matColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{ column.header }}</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{ column.cell(row) }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableConf.columnsToDisplay"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableConf.columnsToDisplay"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</mat-tab>
```

This is a table which on parameters of the selected entity gets dynamic headers. The entity that gets selected has several subentities that each need their own table which should be displayed in tabs. Also there is a time variable that influences all tables.

What I try to do is add and remove those tabs and add my components under it and also have a reference to each of the tables so I can call update methods if the time variable changes.

Comment: Why you need a reference to your tables?

Comment: Good question... I need a reference to the subcomponent (Which in this case would be the Tab the table is in) to update them with new data and to react to changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is probably do not do it. Use the model and `*ngFor` to add tabs and inject them the data you want to.